# Cannot chmode and chown on a ntfs usb drive

Tags: kubuntu, usb-drive, ntfs

I have an NTFS formatted USB drive, on this disk I used to backup using rsync and with 12.04 everything worked.

I've done a 12.10 64 bit fresh install, now when I plug the drive and select open with file manager the dribe is mounted as `rw-------` for my user.

I can create files, I can delete files, but I cannot chown or chmode the files, moreover the rsync saved access rights are completely masked.

What can I do to restore my data with the original access rights and owners?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you usually need to do with NTFS drives (although I haven't installed 12.10, so haven't checked that version).

1. The mounting options must be correct for what you want to do.  I always specifically mount my drives using `/etc/fstab`, and specify where and how it gets mounted.  The flags that are important are the dmask and fmask, and setting the uid and gid.  I am the only user, so I set the uid and gid to my user name, the dmask to 002, and the fmask to 113.
2. You need to set the owner of the directory where the partition is mounted, which will be remembered next time.  You can do this before mounting the drive.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do this... but in 12:04 it worked perfectly. Any hint on how to restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: How were you mounting it in 12.04?  Was it automatic, or did you have an entry in fstab?  If you have a copy of fstab, you can take a look in there to see if it mounted the drive, and if so, copy the entry to the current one (`/etc/fstab`).  It's not hard to edit this text file, and a good thing to know how to do in order to have better control over the system.

Comment: In 12.04 It was mounted automatically. The kde interface shows a set of action for the inserted USB device and I select "open with file manager".

Comment: I don't actually have any removable NTFS drives, but if you want, I could probably help you get the right settings in the fstab file. As long as you are comfortable editing a file from the commandline, it would not be a big deal.  As to why it changed, I don't really know the answer.  You should be able to chown, if you do it as root (ie, with sudo/gksudo).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But for now, I'll use the automount for backups with an EXT4 formatted USB disk

Answer (score 1):

NTFS doesn't support the same right system as you are used to from EXT. For instance it has no owner and no group. The access rights in Windows are managed differently. The owner and the rights for your mounted USB drive are emulated so that you can use it in the file tree.

Comment: Thanks to all. If I cannot do anything else, I'll restore the important files then I'll format the drive as ect4

Comment: Just be aware that you won't be able to read the drive on a Windows system if you do that.  But if you don't need this capability, then ext4 would be a good way to go.